# Installing NPM packages in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

I've tried using ChildProcess to achieve this, here's the code for that:

```js
cp.exec("npm i <package>", {cwd: process.cwd()});
```

Which returns no errors, and doesn't actually install the package

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong or if there are any other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many packages that allow you to install packages, I personally tried using "npm-programmatic" and "npm". The code I showed was valid, but when I was executing it, it was installing the modules to my main project.